# Testing for proportion

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

In a random sample of 81 items taken from a large consignment some were found to be defective. If the standard error of the proportion of defective items in the sample is 1/18 find 95% confidence limits of the percentage of defective items in the consignment.

My try: I tried to calculate the value of p using the given S.E which was approximately equal to 40/81. And then at 95% confidence, the limits I obtained are 38.5% and 60.3%.
Is this the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

$p$ is not "about" $40/81$ but it is exactly $0.5$

$$\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{81}}=\frac{1}{18}$$

That is equivalent to

$$(p-0.5)^2=0$$

Giving exactly

$$p=0.5$$

Using the approx Confidence Interval you get

$$p=(50\pm 10.89)\%$$

Comment: Oh yeah! Thank you @tommik